# Can I have + sign in my textbox?

Tags: php, html

Is there a way I can have a plus sign (+) accepted in my textbox. Actually I have a phone number input box which can accept the (+) sign and then the number. Is there a way to do it. Because when I access it using `$_POST` array in my php, it removes the sign and just gives me the numbers. And this is what I got from google:

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: This is the default encoding. All characters are encoded before sent (spaces are converted to "+" symbols, and special characters are converted to ASCII HEX values)

So if the spaces get converted into '+' then the genuine '+' symbols would get indistinguishable. Right??

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp You can encode the `+` simbol

Comment: I'm just submitting a form with the textbox in it that should accept the '+' sign and the numbers. There is no script written for that. @RhoHappy

Comment: Can you post the code that deals with your POST data? I suspect you are converting the number to an int or something instead of string, which would remove the +.

Comment: Before rushing to provide answers about URL encoding, please consider that PHP takes care automatically of all your encoding needs when posting forms. The OP must be doing something to explicitly corrupt his data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an encoding for plus signs as values.
Self-contained example

```
<?php if ( !isset($_GET['foo']) ) { ?>
<html>
    <head><title>...</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="?">
            <p>
                <input type="text" name="foo" value="+49301234567789" />
                <input type="submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
else {
    if ( 0==strncmp('+', $_GET['foo'], 1) ) {
        echo 'leading plus sign';
    }
    else {
        echo 'no leading plus sign';
    }
}
```

the appended query string is `?foo=%2B49301234567789` where `%2B` encodes the plus.

Comment: The OP is using POST and he claims that `$_POST` already lacks the info. This question is unanswerable unless we see some code.

Comment: Works the same with action="POST" and $_POST. The example is there to show that neither php nor a common webclient prevents a user/script from sending/processing a plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

I used `rawurlencode($_POST['mobile'])` to retrieve the value where `'mobile'` is the text input name and it returns me the value with the '+' sign.